# Interface between keyboard and NXT mindstorm

Tags: nxt

I want to make an NXT program that handles key presses from a user. First, I'd like a message to display asking the user to choose a key on the keyboard (<kbd>S</kbd> or <kbd>M</kbd>), and then depending on the chosen key some actions take place (e.g. starts counting the time). How can I do this? Do I need Bluetooth?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should buy a Bluetooth Card for your PC to connect the NXT with your PC. After that you should program your Bluetooth Card to send specific Bluetooth Signal to the NXT while you are pressing a key. Next you should program your NXT to "react" to the specific signal sent from PC... That's all, it's not too easy...